# Call procedure with parameters within a procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Excel macros, trying to lighten the load a bit so I don't have to write so much code.

On Module 1, I have the following:

```
Sub SendData()
    Dim result As Long, firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim SheetName As Worksheet

    Call BaseCap1("Sheet8")

End Sub
```

On Module 2, I have the following:

```
Sub BaseCap1(SheetName)

    Sheet2.[A1:AC1901].AutoFilter 1, "1"
    Sheet2.[A1:AC1901].AutoFilter 3, "Base Capital"
    Sheet2.[A1:AC1901].AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("Completed"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Sheet2.[E4:E1901,C4:C1901,A4:A1901,J4:J1901,G4:G1901,H4:H1901,I4:I1901,Y4:Y1901].Copy Sheet12.[A1]
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DO NOT USE")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        firstrow = 1
        SheetName.Range("A3").Value = "Facility Base Capital"

        If lastrow = "1" Then
            If IsEmpty(Sheet12.Range("A1").Value) Then
                SheetName.Range("B3").Value = "0"
            Else
                SheetName.Range("B3").Value = lastrow
            End If
        Else
            SheetName.Range("B3").Value = lastrow
        End If

        SheetName.Range("C3").Value = "Completed"
        SheetName.Range("D3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("D" & firstrow & ":D" & lastrow))
        SheetName.Range("E3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("E" & firstrow & ":E" & lastrow))
        SheetName.Range("F3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("F" & firstrow & ":F" & lastrow))
    End With
```

In its current state, I keep getting errors - Run-time error '424': Object required

I have tried several different methods including trying to pass the SheetName variable into another variable with slightly different errors.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this so that it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On which line does the error occur please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SheetName is a string (though you haven't declared it as such).  It has none of the properties you're trying to work with.  You need a reference to the Worksheet whose NAME is SheetName.

Sub BaseCap1(SheetName as String)
' Add this:

```
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Set oSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheetname)
```

Then substitute oSheet for Sheetname throughout the rest of your code.